# Recursivity. Letters in an alphanumeric string

Tags: c, recursion

I'm new to recursivity and the asked job is: ¿How many letters are there in an alphanumeric string? using recursivity of course.

So, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int countl(char*,int,int);

int main(void){
    int n=0,resultado,l;
    char string[20];
    printf("Input a string:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);
    l = strlen(string);
    resultado = countl(string,n,l);
    printf("Ammount of letters: %d",resultado);
}

int countl(char *string,int n,int l){
    if(l>0){
            if(string[n] >= 'A' && string[n] <= 'z'){
                return 1 + countl(string,n+1,l-1);
            }
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Forgot to say that even if the input is '1', the result is 49.

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay attention to the warnings.

If `l>0` *and* the character is not in the `'A'-'z'` range, the function returns garbage.